# Google Places API details to tableview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I'm trying put names details from Google Places to table view but my tableview in UIViewController is still empty. I get data, parse JSON and I see result in console but I cannot put into table view. Please tell me where I'm wrong. I feel that I'm very close to solution. This is result searching:

```
"html_attributions" : [],"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.86879,
           "lng" : 151.194217
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
     "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : false,
        "weekday_text" : []
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 480,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104066891898402903288\"\u003eRhythmboat Cruises\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAWYCQgAwmmu-5Uzelh1besNbSTJyF91IQgS01fZUDgHD8fBu9Y9NGZPjcw9Dt77HVVaSjlnQxbHQhBto_RKmOXs5zb3otmO6YU9z-FdXeVXlRTZGoaC999YS6_5YLBXskEhCCIO6boLQBNEzlGuCKSsemGhTmKEG6Hkgb3YtOGo1HZK6V3sK4ZQ",
           "width" : 640
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
     "reference" : "CnRmAAAAwQ30xJ1IlDWUexRFJl3deTHQo20g1e5mv9aFjQW-UNak4Xi2_f-rirQrTOYK8xxVMpQdf8lI9FMCWLFMKOW3dmXBlIo-RyprHgHcv1GlyC-WwUMlJdu9rwPm4fMOsyHuF3Ftu2-VzJfFJdlSi698EhIQgQhM7DyZnZdttt6nWcyysRoU5TYhn0mo6C0JQsrb2AOOuZB0uUE",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Pyrmont Bay Wharf (Near Australia Maritime Museum), Pyrmont, NSW 2009"
  },
```

and here is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

@interface PlacesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *connectionData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *messageArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *messageTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *activityView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

and my implementation in ViewController.m

```
#import "PlacesViewController.h"
//#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Places.h"

#define kMessageBoardURLString @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=myAPI_KEY"

@interface PlacesViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlacesViewController
@synthesize connectionData;
@synthesize messageArray;
@synthesize messageTable;
@synthesize activityView;
@synthesize activityIndicator;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection delegate methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.connectionData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.connectionData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    connection = nil;
    connectionData = nil;

    NSLog(@"Connect error. Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *retString =
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[connectionData bytes]];

    NSLog(@"Return json: %@", retString);

    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:connectionData
                                    options:0
                                      error:&parseError];

    if (!parseError) {
        self.messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
        NSLog(@"Table of json to: %@", json);
        [messageTable reloadData];
    } else {
        NSString *err = [parseError localizedDescription];
        NSLog(@"parse error: %@", err);
    }

    connection = nil;
    connectionData = nil;

    [self.activityView setHidden:YES];
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

#pragma mark - Table data source

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *message = [self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self messageArray] count];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMessageTable:nil];
    [self setActivityView:nil];
    [self setActivityIndicator:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear, refreshing messages");
    //start activity indicator
    [self.activityView setHidden:NO];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    NSURL *msgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kMessageBoardURLString];
    NSURLRequest *msgRequest =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:msgURL
                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                 timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection =
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:msgRequest
                                    delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        NSMutableData *connData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        [self setConnectionData:connData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cannot connect...");
        [self.activityView setHidden:YES];
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    connectionData = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Maybe you forget to set ViewController as _dataSourse_ and _delegate_ of your TableView?

Comment: No, I'm setting dataSource and delegate of my TableView.